# How to append a DIV Banner Block to a HTML Page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.3.2 and I was wondering if the following is achievable and if so, how can it be done.

Basically, I have an iframe src page that displays a report to a user. Now because it's in an iframe, there is no banner on that page but I do allow the user to detach the iframe into a new browser window using window.open, so that they can see more info.

My question is, as I am opening the iframe page into a new browser, I need to manipulate the html and append, at body part of the page, a div section, that contains a banner.

Basically, in this div, I have my company's banner (logo and name), I just need a means of attaching this to the top of the page when a user detaches the page from the iframe.

Comment: I'm wondering, how do you do the window.open thing? Could you post some code please? Nice question btw!

Comment: Hi Maxim Z. Basically, from another thread I got help from, from the stackoverflow people, I basically check for the window.name I have assigned as the second parameter to the window.open function and pass in my required URL, i.e. window.open(new_url ,'dtchWin','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, status=no, resizable=yes'); Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleaner way would be having class in html or body tag, which you switch after 'detaching' iframe. While page is in iframe class is for example 'in-iframe'.

And you have CSS like:

```
.in-iframe #banner, .in-iframe #footer {
    display: none;
}
```

So the banner will be actually always on the page, but sometimes it will be hidden.

IFrame html (note link with anchor for iframe):

```
<iframe src="/report/xxx/#hidebanner"></iframe>
<a href="/report/xxx/" target="_blank">open report in separate window</a>
```

Report page html:

```
...
<html>
...
<body>
<script> if (location.hash == '#hidebanner') { $('body').addClass('in-iframe'); } </script>
...
```

Comment: Thanks Qwerty, but could you pls provide an example on how to perform the switch between classes? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that Qwerty meant the following: in your window.open switching thing, add the following: `$(".in-iframe").show();`.

Comment: Hi, I'm still confused as to how to apply Qwerty's approach? A detailed example would be most appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: tonsils, actually if you use some kind of script for generating pages, you could just add additional param to skip your banners. For example iframe src=http://example.com/report/xxx/?hidebanner=1. When user opens page without '?hidebanner=1' part you keep banners. Also see JS approach in updated answer.